# Кэширование сайта отключить

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, кэширование

Всем привет. Есть сайт на `codeighniher`, прикол в следующем. Если, я что-то меняю в стилях или `js`, в отдельных файлах, то, чтобы получить изменение мне нужно обновить страницу с очисткой кэша (`ctrl+f5` в chrome) .
 Если просто обновить страницу то никаких изменений по сайту нету.
 Если писать стили в самом `html`, то без проблем меняется информация простым <kbd>f5</kbd>.
 В чем может быть проблема? Где копать? На всяких случай скидываю файл `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|js|images|stylesheets|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<Files *>
Header set Cache-Control: "private, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0"
Header set Expires: 0
Header set Pragma: no-cache
</Files>
```

Comment: Покажите лучше какие заголовки реально отдаются, а не конфиг. Это исключит много вопросов. Вкладка сеть, если в Хроме.

Comment: А где найти эти заголовки, открыл network, но там капец много чего вышло

Comment: а вы отфильтруйте по .js или .css. Смотреть нужно `Response Headers` - их и покажите. `cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` - вот что стоит на SO. Хотя ваши заголовки по причине `max-age=0` также должны запрещать. Жду заголовки

Comment: Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from memory cache)
Remote Address: 195.210.46.23:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000

Comment: Вот теперь надо разбираться, почему `Cache-Control: max-age=315360000 `. Какие веб-сервера стоят?

Comment: у хостинга покупаем, наверно apache старый добрый

Comment: Это - не ответ. Есть подозрение, что стоит перед этим делом nginx, и апачу вообще не отдается управление для CSS JS.

Comment: вы правые есть nginx и apache

Comment: Вам нужно для разработки сбрасывать кеш? Дописывайте в `src="/js/scrips.js?<?=date('ymdHis', filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/js/scrips.js'))?>"`. Это самый простой путь. Иначе - правьте конфиг Nginx

Comment: Напишите в ответ, приму как правильный Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `Nginx` стоит перед `Apache` и настроен для быстрой отдачи статики (CSS, JS, картинки), и управление Apache даже не передается. Поэтому настройки из `.htaccess` не влияют на заголовки, а Nginx часто настраивают на длительное кеширование:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|bmp|txt)$ {
  access_log        off;
  expires           14d; # кеширование в браузере на 14 дней
  break;
}
```

Первое, что следует выяснить - какие именно заголовки ответа передаются с веб-сервера. Это можно сделать во вкладке `Network` в консоли разработчика Хрома или `Сеть` в Firefox. Далее фильтруем по маске `.css` или `.js` и обращаем внимание на заголовки:

- `Expires` (недостаток - на клиенте может стоять неверное время) и
- `Cache-Control` (лишен этого недостатка).

> В инструментах разработчика Хрома, в столбце Size надписи `from disk cache` и `from memory cache` как раз указывают на загрузку ресурса из кеша. А опция `Disable cache` полностью отключает кеш, ресурсы всегда загружаются с сервера, но только пока открыты инструменты разработчика.

Через curl:

```
curl -I "http://site.ru/js/scrips.js"
```

Чтобы кеширования не было, должно стоять:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

или

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

или `Expires` указывает на дату в прошлом (минус 1 год, например).

Чтобы понять, участвует ли Apache в формировании ответа сервера, можно поставить дополнительный заголовок, через тот же `.htaccess`:

```
# Ставим заголовок для понимания
Header set BackServer "Apache"
```

Если настроить веб-сервер невозможно (как в заданном вопросе), для файла следует указать дату его модификации в виде `GET`-параметра, например, так:

```
<script src="/js/scrips.js?<?=date('ymdHis',
  filemtime($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/js/scrips.js'))?>"></script>
```

Кеширование в этом случае работать также будет, но при изменении файла `GET`-параметр изменится, что заставит браузер загрузить новую версию.